# Wrong version of npm package showing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I need version `1.69.1` of `react-native-webrtc` `npm` package installed in my project.

When I use the command `npm show react-native-webrtc version` in the terminal it returns `1.75.0`.

However there is no trace of this version of the package in my project, not in the `package.json` or `package-lock.json`, only references to `1.69.1` as you can see, although in the `yarn.lock` there is `1.69.2`:

[image]

I have deleted the node modules folder but it doesn't change anything. How can I make sure the right version is installed?

Comment: Npm show is for querying packages in the registry afaik, not for packages installed in your project. 1.75.0 is probably the latest version

Comment: You can do `npm ls react-native-webrtc` or `yarn ls react-native-webrtc` to see what versions you have installed in node_modules.

Comment: Are you using `npm` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn` and `yarn.lock`? In your `package-lock.json` the version is specified as `^1.69.1` which means any version that is compatible with `1.69.1` - see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004. That will be the newest version matching `1.x.x` which appears to be `1.75.0`. If you need an exact version you need to set your dependency to be `"1.69.1"` without the `^` for an exact match.